# Sum of values in a Drop Down Menu Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i'm just starting out on my first website and would like to set a limit for the sum of 4 inputs from different drop down menu's. However my code doesn't seem to work. Here's the HTML code in reference for the JS code
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGDPQ.png)

```
function quantityLimit(limit) {

  var e = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0];
  var limit =  limit;
  var value = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].onchange = function() {
        var sum += value;
    }
    if (sum<6||sum >6){
        alert("You must pick 6 bottles in total");
        this.selected = false;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Edit your question, add the HTML part also

Comment: Have added it as a link under "HTML" because the HTML Code is from developer mode , am not allowed to post pictures as this is a new account.

Answer (score 0):

The variable sum is declared inside the onchange function and it will not be accessible outside.

Move it a level higher

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    let sum = 0;
    e[i].onchange = function() {
        sum += value;
    }
    if (sum<6||sum >6){
        alert("You must pick 6 bottles in total");
        this.selected = false;
    }
  }
```